# Custom Sorting with variables in VBA

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

The macro below is a custom sort that I recorded. I replaced the actual table name with variable so I can run this for any other table name. I didn't want it to be specific to one name. When I run the macro I get a:

> Run-time error '1004': the item with the specified name wasn't found

When I click the help button it sends me to Excel help menu. 
Could you guys let me know what I am missing?
And if possible is there a way to shorten up my code. I know recordings can be long.

**Note all of this is in a table

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim TableName As String

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 TableName = sh.Name


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TableName).ListObjects(TableName).sort. _
      SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TableName).ListObjects(TableName).sort. _
      SortFields.Add Key:=Range(TableName, [BEVEL]), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,
      Order:=xlAscending, _
      CustomOrder:="BEVEL_YES_MITER,BEVEL_NO_RADIUS", DataOption:=xlSortNormal _

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TableName).ListObjects("TableName").sort. _
      SortFields.Add Key:=Range(TableName, [MATERIAL]), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
      Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TableName).ListObjects(TableName).sort. _
      SortFields.Add Key:=Range(TableName, [Length]), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
      Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TableName).ListObjects(TableName).sort
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
     End With
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if I am using the word variables correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I notice that though most of your table references are like this `..ListObjects(TableName)..`, one of them looks like this `..ListObjects("TableName")..`, so I'm guessing that's where the error is coming from.

However, in general I'd recommend putting not just the table-name into a variable, but also the table itself, like this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim TableName As String
Dim theTable As ListObject

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 TableName = sh.Name
 Set theTable = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TableName).ListObjects(TableName)

    theTable.sort.SortFields.Clear
    theTable.sort.SortFields.Add _
      Key:=Range(TableName & "[BEVEL]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,
      Order:=xlAscending, _
      CustomOrder:="BEVEL_YES_MITER,BEVEL_NO_RADIUS", DataOption:=xlSortNormal 

    theTable.sort.SortFields.Add 
      Key:=Range(TableName & "[MATERIAL]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
      Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    theTable.sort.SortFields.Add  _
      Key:=Range(TableName & "[Length]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
      Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With theTable.sort
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
     End With
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

---

(Note: corrected the line breaks)

---

(Note: corrected Range table-column name parameters)

Comment: For some reason it doesnt like the following:


theTable.sort. _
      SortFields.Add Key:=Range(TableName, [BEVEL]), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,
      Order:=xlAscending, _
      CustomOrder:="BEVEL_YES_MITER,BEVEL_NO_RADIUS", DataOption:=xlSortNormal _

Comment: Oh, right.  You cannot put a space or line break(" _ ") before or after dots (".") in a reference path.  You can only put them between  operands, etc. Basically wherever a space would normally go.

Comment: @user2792786 OK, I have corrected the line breaks in my code above.

Comment: It still doesnt like it bud:

`theTable.sort.SortFields.Add _
      Key:=Range(TableName, [BEVEL]), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
      Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:="BEVEL_YES_MITER,BEVEL_NO_RADIUS", DataOption:=xlSortNormal`

Comment: The item with the specified name wasn't found

Comment: @MichaelACruz Hmm, looks like you are passing incorrectly constructed table-column reference strings to the `Range` method.  I will correct in my code ... done.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for all your help Barry